# If $G$ is a group of finite order and $p$ is a prime, then $N\triangleleft G,\ H\leq G,\ |G/N|=p\Longrightarrow H\subset N$ or $NH= G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

If $\displaystyle N$ is a normal subgroup of finite group $\displaystyle G$ (finite group) and $\displaystyle H$ is a subgroup of $\displaystyle G$ such that the quotient group $\displaystyle G/N\ $is of prime order, then prove that either $\displaystyle H\subset N$ or $\displaystyle NH=G$.

Since $\displaystyle G/N$ is of prime order $\displaystyle p$, it must be cyclic. It follows that $\displaystyle \exists g\in G\setminus N$ such that

$$G/N=\langle gN \rangle$$
Suppose that $\displaystyle H\not\subset N$.

It follows that $\displaystyle \exists h\in H\setminus N$ and therefore $\displaystyle hN=g^{i} N$ for some $\displaystyle i\geqslant 1$. I am stuck here and don't know how to show $\displaystyle NH=G$ from here. I'll appreciate any hint in this. Thanks.

Comment: Since $N$ is normal, $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$. This subgroup contains $N$, so you may use the second isomorphism theorem.

Comment: The body and the title are different. Which are you asking?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: I have fixed the typo in title. Thanks.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: I’m afraid, by this chapter second isomorphism theorem has not been introduced so I am not allowed to use that. This is an exercise problem from chapter on Quotient/ Factor groups from Gallian’s abstract algebra.

Comment: Hint: if $H \not \subseteq N$ then compute the order $|G/NH|$. You want to show it's $1$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: That seems to be a good idea and will probably answer my question as well. But the problem is that NH may not be normal in G so I can’t define $G/{NH}$, please correct me if I’m wrong. Also, I wonder how we can proceed from where I l got stuck as shown in the post. Thanks.

Comment: You can define $G/NH$ as a set of cosets because $NH$ is a subgroup (why is it a subgroup?). Normality is only essential to show that $G/NH$ has a group structure. For a further hint, the proof I have in mind uses the fact that $G/N$ has prime order. You need primality, so somehow you have to make a divisibility argument.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: NH is a subgroup because 1) if $nh\in NH$ then $(nh)^{-1}=h^{-1}n^{-1}=n'h^{-1}\in NH$ (since N is normal in G) so NH is closed under inverse 2) If $nh, n'h'\in NH$ then $nhn'h'=nn''hh'\in NH$ hence closed under group operation. Therefore, by Lagrange's theorem $|G/N|=[G:NH][NH:N]=p$ so either a) [G:NH]=1 and [NH:N]=p or b)  [G:NH]=p and [NH:N]=1. In case a):G=NH, In case b): NH=N and since $H\subset NH$, it follows that $H\subset N$. And hence proved. Thank you!

Comment: That's exactly right! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $NH$ is a subgroup since $N$ is normal. In addition $N \subseteq NH \subseteq G$, so $|G:N|=|G:NH| \cdot |NH:N|$ is a prime, so ....